# How can I print/get the errors on gatling report?

Tags: karate

On the error section from the gatling report I get this -> (classpath:tottus/api/checkout/checkout-endpoint.feature:119 status 200) pointing where it fails, but is there a way to print the ERROR from gatling?

Answer (score 1):

Currently no. You may have to get it from `karate.log`. This may need community contributions to improve.